# Excel: Userform Textbox match function

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to get the userform to update other fields when I update a textbox.
My problem is that even though I write `TextBox1.Value` it still treats my input as text and thus only finds a match if I format my numbers in the table as text.

Below is my current code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error Resume Next
ComboBox2.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnamn"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(TextBox1.Value, Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnr"), 0), 1)
```

End Sub

This code works but is not connected to the userform.
(I put in a number (155001) that the range:"Projektnr" contains)
So it is the first part of the Match function that doesn't work.

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error Resume Next
ComboBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnamn"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(155001, Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnr"), 0), 1)
```

End Sub

I tried gizlmeiers suggestion and it still refuses to find a match.
I attatch that code as well:

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
On Error Resume Next
Test = CInt(TextBox1.Value)
ComboBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnamn"), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Test, Sheets("Projekt").Range("Projektnr"), 0), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to compare two numbers, but the one in the textbox is interpreted as a string?

You can tell vba to interpret it as a number by using CINT()

```
CINT(TextBox1.Value)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me :)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with the Worksheet.Index function?

Comment: I include a link to my current file:
http://www.filedropper.com/testfile_4

Start by clicking on the "- Avsluta Projekt" button on sheet one.
It will take you to the small userform.
My gol is to make it easier to se what project that's corresponding to a certain number, minimizing the risk of closing the wrong project.
when pressing the button the macro thould also use the match function to locate the row and move that row to the sheet "Avslutade projekt".